# How to get the contents of a Third Party lazy loading page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Via a Chrome extension, I'm trying to get and modify the contents of a third-party page. Everything works for the part of the content that's immediately visible on initial page load.

The problem is that this page has a lazy-load/ajax pagination. **To get all of the content I have to click "view all" (ajax link)** (and I believe this works essentially the same way as lazy-loading that's why I put that keyword in the title).

Upon clicking that link (on that third-party website) all content gets loaded and becomes visible to the user **but when I view source there's still only the originally loaded content present in the source code**. i.e. none of the freshly loaded content can be found anywhere when I view page source after the new content has been loaded. The content is visible to the end user but not visible to me when I check the source code.

Initially, I tried to overcome the problem by using setInteval and checking the page content every second but as that wasn't working I checked the source code and sure enough, none of the newly loaded content is visible in the source code. No wonder my Chrome extension can't get that content.

Another confusing thing I just realized when typing here: 
When I view source code, **even the initial HTML content** that my Chrome extension is detecting/loading **is NOT actually present in the source code!** **It actually sits in a JavaScript array.** So, somehow, my Chrome extension is correctly getting the initial HTML content that's constructed from that JS array. But it's NOT getting the content that gets loaded after clicking the "view all" ajax link on that page (even though I'm using setInteval and checking for new content every second).

**What are possible solutions for this?**

I can't post the link to the page because it's the "my certificates" page on Lynda.com and I don't know of a publicly accessible website/page with the same behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should find the actual service running in network-panel, when lazy loading happens, and then follow following code

```
   //recursively make calls and gatther responses. cb is callback to run on response, end is end page-no (end of recursion condition) , pageId is the attribute changing in every subsequent lazy-loading call.
var callIfRequiredConfigured = ({cb,end,step=1,pageURL,pageId})=>callIfRequired = ()=>{
    currentCounter = currentCounter + step;
    if (currentCounter > end) {
        return;
    }
    (async(currentCounter)=>{

        queueCounter++;
        //modify this as needed
        const r = await fetch(pageURL+currentCounter,{credentials:"same-origin"});
          //queueCounter to not make more than 6 calls at once
        if (queueCounter > 6) {
            return;
        }
        var response = await r.text();
        cb(response);
        queueCounter--;
        callIfRequired();
    }
    )(currentCounter);

};

var call = (config)=>{
    const callIfRequired = callIfRequiredConfigured(config);
    callIfRequired();
}


call({
    cb: (response)=>{
        //do somrthing with response
    }
    ,
    end: 50,
    step: 1,
    pageId: 'PageNumber=',
    pageURL: `https://www.lynda.com/home/CertificateOfCompletion/GetCertificatesByFilter?Start=0&Limit=99999&SortBy=CompletionDate&SortByOrder=1&_=[my_personal_id]&PageNumber=`
});
```

So main effort will be to deduce the service endpoint here and how it changes in subsequest requests. I have updated the url given in comments, but see if the fetch call is successful. Also this url should also have `[my_personal_id]` as given in url.

Comment: I checked the network panel and see that when I click the "view all" ajax link the following URL gets called: 
https://www.lynda.com/home/CertificateOfCompletion/GetCertificatesByFilter?PageNumber=1&Start=0&Limit=99999&SortBy=CompletionDate&SortByOrder=1&_=[my_personal_id]  Can you give me any pointers as to what could I do with that?

Comment: @WebDevBooster try now. I have made changes with this url. when you run above code, do check that fetch call is successful in network-panel, else make changes to make it successful.